# How to code to use different proxy on every request in Python web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I have a proxy list in a csv as below

http://202.83.162.214:8080

http://37.187.119.226:3128

How to use each proxy on every request of BeautifulSoup of URL while web scrapring using Python 3?

Comment: I'd start with looking at how to read text from a csv first so that your proxy list becomes just a python list of strings to simplify your question.

Answer (score 2):

You could read the proxies from the CSV file into list using `readlines()`. You will then have to loop over the list and make a new request with the current proxy server in the list.

If you are using `requests`, you can do

```
proxies = {'http': '<http_proxy>', 'https': '<https_proxy>'}
```

and then do

```
requests.post(url, proxies=proxies)
```

inside the loop

The following code should work, assuming the proxies in the CSV file are on separate lines:

```
proxy_list = []

with open('file.txt') as fp:
    proxy_list = fp.readlines()

for proxy in proxy_list:
    proxies = {'http': proxy.strip()}

    req = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying

Shall i try like this:

data = open("input/InputURL_CSV_Format.csv").read()
dataFile = StringIO(data)
csvReader = csv.reader(dataFile)
for row in csvReader:
    prox= row[0]
    proxies = {'prox'}
    source_code = requests.get(prox, proxies=proxies)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup_v = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'lxml')

Comment: Hi Aaron,

Can you please write a sample script to meet my requirement here?

Comment: Thanks a lot Aaron

My proxy list is separated by "Enter". ie. Each proxy is in each line in csv
No comma is there

Please tell me how to modify that code to that

Comment: @Saranaone use `readlines()` instead of `read`. Check the edit in my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot..I implement this and let you know the result

How to know my proxy is processed?

Comment: @Saranaone Just do `requests.get('https://ipinfo.io/json', proxies=<test_proxy>)` and check the IP address of the response. And replace <test_proxy> with one of the proxy IP addresses from the list to test if it is working